# Integral Solution

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

During my attempt to solve the non-linear ODE

\begin{equation}
m\ddot{x}+x-x^3=0
\end{equation}
I have stumbled across the integral:
\begin{equation}
\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}\left( \frac{x^4}{2}-x^2\right)+2c}}dx}
\end{equation}
which is blocking my way to solution. Now, I have some experience with these integrals, but apparently not enough, to know that I will probably use a hyperbolic trigonometric substitution in order to reach the solution.

So, what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it supposed to be $dt$?

Comment: @BenLongo my bad, thanks!